# Remove Region Number

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to do basic regex thing but still cannot figure it out. I need to remove the region number code and only get the number onwards. For example:

> (+60)123456789 --> 0123456789

I have try using this regex expression `replace(/\D+/g, '')` but the number `6` from the region code still there which make it `60123456789`

Answer (score 0):

I would use the following find and replace, in regex mode:

```
Find:    ^\(\+\d+\)
Replace: (empty)
```

Here is a working regex [demo](https://regex101.com/r/a3X9NW/1).

Comment: Is it possible to do it without substitution? Your regex is perfectly work in the demo however when I put it to my code, company_phone_no: value.replace(/^\(\+\d+\)/gm, '') it still remain the same as above.

Comment: You are not using the regex from my answer, as the parentheses need to be escaped.  Use: `value.replace(/^\(\+\d+\)/gm, '')`

Comment: I'm sorry that's a typing error. Thank you for having your time replying to me, but I already use your regex as per given `company_phone_no: value.replace(/^\(\+\d+\)/gm, '')` but the problem is still there. It return `company_phone_no: "+(60)123456789"`.

Comment: You need to make an assignment: `value = value.replace(/^\(\+\d+\)/gm, '')`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep the trailing zero(s) from the number, you can capture those in a group, and then use the group value in the replacement.

```js
const s = "(+60)123456789";
const regex = /\(\+\d*[1-9](0*)\)/;
const m = s.replace(regex, "$1");
console.log(m);
```

If you want to take the digits only after the leading parenthesis parts, you can also take the trailing digits until the end of the string.

```js
const s = "(+60)123456789";
const regex = /\d+$/;
const m = s.match(regex);
if (m) console.log(m[0]);
```